# How to add validations for div tags in AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, validation, angularjs-forms

I'm trying to add validations to my Angular js code. I'm using div tags instead of form. Do I need to change something in .js or should I just add required in my input tag

```
<input required type="..." name="..." ng-model="..." />
```

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use a `<div>` element instead of a `<form>` element, use the `ng-form` directive:

```
<div ng-form="name1">
    <input name="input1" ng-model="data.firstName" required />
    <input name="input2" ng-model="data.lastName" required />
</div>
```

For more information:

- [AngularJS ng-form Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngForm)
- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Forms](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms)